# new of incomplete type compiles when wrapped in template

Tags: c++, templates, forward-declaration

Consider this code, with an obvious compile error: (1)

```
struct A;
struct B {
  B() { new A(); } // error: allocation of incomplete type 'A'
};
```

Using a `unique_ptr` will not help either: (2)

```
struct A;
struct B {
  B() { std::make_unique<A>(); } // error: due to ~unique_ptr()
};
```

Then (to my great surprise) I found out, that this **will** compile: (3)

```
struct A;
struct B {
  B() { std::make_unique<A>(); }
};
struct A {}; // OK, when a definition is added **below**
```

Then I checked, whether this helps with `new` as well - **nope**: (4)

```
struct A;
struct B {
  B() { new A(); } // error: allocation of incomplete type 'A'
};
struct A {};
```

I figured it has something to do with `template`s and in fact: wrapping `new` inside a `template` **does** compile: (5)

```
template <typename T> 
T* my_new() { return new T(); } // OK, when wrapped in template
struct A;
struct B {
  B() { my_new<A>(); }
};
struct A {};
```

And just for the sake of completeness, removing the definition of `A` raises an error again: (6)

```
template <typename T> 
T* my_new() { return new T(); } // error: allocation of incomplete type 'A'
struct A;
struct B {
  B() { my_new<A>(); }
}; 
// do note: definition of A removed
```

What's going on here? As far as I *understood*, the compiler **must** know the size/definition of `A` to allocate it, thus merely declaring it, is not sufficient. In addition I believed, that the definition must **precede** the allocation.

This seems to be correct, when using `new` *directly* (1,4). But when `new` is wrapped, it is apparent that I am mistaken (2,3,5,6).

Possible explanations I found so far are:

- The check for completed types is delayed until the `template` instantiation occurs. I think this is correct, but in my case the *direct* use of `new A()` and the call to `my_new<A>()` occur virtually on the same position. So this cannot be the reason. Right?
- Using incomplete types as `template` Arguments might be *undefined behavior*. Is this really true? Even when enabling all warnings, the compiler will not complain. Also comparing 5 and 6 seems to suggest, that the compiler is smart enough to figure out, that the definition follows below (thus virtually making the type complete).

Why 4 is considered to be incorrect, whilst 5 compiles (or is 5 just spuriously compiling undefined behavior [but then 3 must be flawed as well, right?])?

btw: tested with clang++-3.5.0 and g++-4.9.2

Comment: http://blog.llvm.org/2009/12/dreaded-two-phase-name-lookup.html

Comment: In case it's unclear, because that article only addresses the stricter side of two phase name lookup, templates names aren't instantiated until another pass over the code, after it's already went through and read the definition of `A`, which is why it compiles.

Comment: It's a common implementation technique to delay template instantiation until the end of the translation unit. Your code is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

§14.6.4.1 [temp.point]/p1,8, emphasis mine:

> 1 For a function template specialization, a member function template
>   specialization, or a specialization for a member function or static
>   data member of a class template, if the specialization is implicitly
>   instantiated because it is referenced from within another template
>   specialization and the context from which it is referenced depends on
>   a template parameter, the point of instantiation of the specialization
>   is the point of instantiation of the enclosing specialization.
>   Otherwise, **the point of instantiation for such a specialization
>   immediately follows the namespace scope declaration or definition that
>   refers to the specialization.**
>
> 8 A specialization for a function template, a member function template,
>   or of a member function or static data member of a class template may
>   have multiple points of instantiations within a translation unit, and
>   **in addition to the points of instantiation described above, for any
>   such specialization that has a point of instantiation within the
>   translation unit, the end of the translation unit is also considered a
>   point of instantiation**. A specialization for a class template has at
>   most one point of instantiation within a translation unit. A
>   specialization for any template may have points of instantiation in
>   multiple translation units. **If two different points of instantiation
>   give a template specialization different meanings according to the one
>   definition rule (3.2), the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic
>   required.**

There are two points of instantiation of `my_new<A>`, one at the end of the definition of `B`, and one at the end of the translation unit. Since those two points will result in different meanings (for snippets 3 and 5), the program is ill-formed NDR (i.e., it has undefined behavior).

Comment: Should clarify that it's (3) and (5) that have different meanings, (6) has the same meaning in both points - neither of which is valid. Right?